# How could I create a matplotlib bar graph based off a txt file including keylogging data in python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I created a key logging program in python that records the time and date of every key I type into a text document. I want to create a bar graph using matplotlib that reads the text document and on the x-axis has every letter I typed and on the y-axis is the number of types I typed each letter. Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('keylogtest.txt', delim_whitespace=True, names=('date', 'time', 'key'))

print(df.head())
```

The code prints out the following:

```
         date           time        key
0  2020-06-16  20:47:46,054:        't'
1  2020-06-16  20:47:46,124:        'h'
2  2020-06-16  20:47:46,230:        'i'
3  2020-06-16  20:47:46,292:        's'
4  2020-06-16  20:47:46,434:  Key.space
```

I'm not sure how to continue from here. Does anyone have any ideas on what I could do?

Comment: `df['key'].value_counts().plot.bar()`.

Comment: When I put this into my code, nothing shows up. I tried printing this line and this showed up:

Comment: AxesSubplot(0.125,0.11;0.775x0.77)

Comment: `df['key'].value_counts().plot.bar();plt.show()`?